# Cognito, API Gateway and Lambda assuming the identity of the cognito user

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I’m building a React app, using API Gateway, lambda and cognito (basically starting from the https://serverless-stack.com tutorial). I would like to setup fine grained access control to my DynamoDb (i.e. through IAM policies that restrict access to DynamoDb tables based upon the logged-in user - like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_rows.html)

AFAIK, a lambda function assumes a service role, as defined in the serverless.yml file, that has in itself nothing to do with the AIM policy that is attached to the logged in cognito user. I know that using an aim_authorizer, I can get info on the logged in user.

My question: is it possible to have the lambda do AWS calls on behalf of the given cognito user, thus honoring the IAM policies attached to that user? (a bit similar as to how the serverless-stack tutorial interacts with S3)

All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify to any AWS client library which credentials to use in order to sign requests (by default they are taken from the runtime environment):

```
import { DocumentClient } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';

const client = new DocumentClient({
    credentials: ...
});
```

Those security credentials are obtain via STS. There are various scenarios how to get a hold of the user's identity to obtain credentials, but usually you would either `assumeRole`, if you have an arn of a role, or `assumeRoleWithWebIdentity`, if there is an actual user that did a flow of OpenID Connect:

```
import { Credentials, STS } from 'aws-sdk';

const sts = new STS();
const stsResponse = await sts.assumeRole({ RoleArn: 'can-be-cognito-group-arn' }).promise();
// or
// const stsResponse = await sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity({ WebIdentityToken: 'open-id-token' }).promise();

const credentials = new Credentials(
    response.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    response.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    response.Credentials.SessionToken);
```